# Android application recording audio don't allow whatsapp send audio

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, nonblocking

I'm working on an android application that records audio in a background service.
The problem is the following: while my app is recording I cannot send whatsapp audio or record a video with device camera.

I'm using AudioRecord with this param:

```
new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100, 
AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize * 
5);
```

And AudioManager as:

```
am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

Is there any way to record audio without blocking microphone for others apps?

Thanks and sorry by my poor English

Answer (score 0):

Yup, (google settings - search and now - voice - OK google detection - from any screen(uncheck))

Problem gone!

Comment: Hi, tanks by your anwer

Comment: The problem not is with Google assistant, the problem is when my app is recording audio, the microphone is blocking  for third party apps.

Comment: I've tested it and the problem is not fixed